# How to get field from config.ini file eclipse

Tags: eclipse, configuration, eclipse-rcp

I would like to change some data before my RCP eclipse product will start. For this purpose as I got to know it better to use config.ini file. Before that I tested getting some data from VM arguments of configuration by this way:

```
System.getProperty("var_name")
```

then I tried to set field in configuration of my eclipse product:

[image]

but I can't get it by my way which was posted above. How I can set some pre-launch eclipse product fields which then can be changed?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you saying that "test" value is not being added to the generated config.ini?

Comment: @greg-449, yes, where I can check it? by getting it via getProperty I received null

Comment: Configuration properties and Java properties are different things. Setting a Java property is done via _Launching Arguments_ (in the _Launching_ instead of the _Configuration_ tab), in your case with the VM argument `-Dtest="hello world"`. In your application, in the `<yourRCP>.ini` file instead of the `configuration/config.ini` file.

Comment: Are you building the RCP and then running that, or are you testing it in Eclipse with Run Eclipse Application (which doesn't use the product file config)?

Comment: @greg-449, I tested is via Run Eclipse Application via setting vm arguments and then would like to see similar behavior in the production too

Comment: You can set the VM Arguments in the same way in the product file - on the Launching tab.

Comment: hm... @greg-449, you helped me one more time ) thank you :D